# WooCommerce Pre-Orders Not Triggering a Google Analytics Conversion

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-analytics

I have a WooCommerce shop with the official Pre-Orders plugin. The issue is that my data in GA is not reflecting the conversions I am getting via the pre-orders.

I believe, but am not 100% sure that this is because GA is only passed conversion data from WooCommerce when the order is marked as "processing" or "completed".

The pre-order plugin automatically marks all pre order sales as a special status "Pre ordered"

If I manually change the order from "Pre ordered" to "Processing" ... something fires and GA sees the sale and marks it as a conversion.

What's the best solution here so that I can leave the status as Pre ordered? Part of the issue is that if I manually go in and change the status to "Processing" , the customer will receive a second "confirmation" email and may think there's been an error and they've been charged twice.

Also, it's just not an elegant solution, especially as the volume of sales are picking up.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is correct. If something is pre-ordered, it's not a conversion (yet). When the order has been processed, the conversion should be registered.

I would keep the setup but with a change in the email after a customer has pre-ordered. Let them know you have received their pre-order and will notify them once their order is processed. And sent them a confirmation when you are processing the order.

Comment: but i would like the pre-order to count as a conversion in GA. It counts as a conversion in the Facebook pixel. They are making the payment at the time of the pre-order... it would help with knowing the conversion rate and retargeting ads if I could get GA to see a pre-order as a conversion.

Comment: It seems that order data is being sent to GA based on the status of the order. And not when a customer reaches the order confirmation page. Maybe you can Auto change the status from pre-ordered to processing (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-changed-of-status/) and skip the pre-ordered email?